# in an adjective phrase

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

In a English dictionary, I run across a sentence I can't grasp.

> 1. I sat down deep in contemplation.

Can I change the sentence into the following.

> 2. I sat down and I was deep in contemplation.

Does the both have the same meaning? If not, what difference there is?

and can I say that the phrase(deep in contemplation) is an adjective phrase and a complement of the subject

Comment: Yes, "deep in contemplation" is an adjective phrase. Yes, it's a complement, but of the verb "sat". not of the subject "I".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *deep in contemplation* describes **I**, the subject.

I think I would put 2 as
*I was deep in contemplation, and I sat down.*
That just seems a more natural order of events: the contemplation was an existing state, and the sitting down occurred while I was in that state.